# How to add query parameters to receive the updated repositories for a specific timespan

Tags: github, github-api

Using this query parameters as the api call below it was possible to received repositories created in a specific time span in an ascend order.

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=%22analysis%22created:2017-08-14..2021-04-16T23:34:59Z&sort=created&order=asc&per_page=100&page=10
```

How is it possible to form an api call in order to receive the updated repositories in a specific timespan? I tried this but it is not the correct option

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=%22analysis%22updated:2008-01-01..2023-11-27&sort=updated&order=asc&per_page=100&page=1
```